# Invalid or Unexpected token error in column list for a Datatable

Tags: javascript, django, datatable

I have a datatable in a django template i'm using, and when I load the page on my server I get a syntax error at the first element in my dictionary.

```
/** Data table setup **/
    var tb = $(".data-table").DataTable({
        "order" : [[ 0, "asc"]],
        "dom"  : "ifrtp",
        "columns" : [
            {"title" : “ID”},
            {"title" : “User”},
            {"title" : “Account”},
            {"title" : “Job Name“},
            {"title" : “State”},
            {"title" : “Partition”},
    .../** omitted a few rows **/
        ],
        "pageLength": 100
    });
```

The underline for the error appears right under "ID" and I'm not sure why. This code is all adapted from a similar template in the same project I'm working on, and it does the same thing, except the values corresponding to each "title" are different. That template works perfectly, so I dont know why this one does not.

Comment: Smart quotes are not valid quoting characters in JS code source.

Comment: How do I change what type of quotes I'm typing? I'm not that familiar with writing code in text editors.

Comment: ??? The most of the quoting is correct, how did you do that?

Comment: That was all copy-pasted out of a similar template that already existed

Comment: Did a replace all on the smart quotes, it works now. Thank you.